# Pre-select a role on user register form and hide from display?

Tags: users, hooks

I have this scenario that I am trying to walk through. I am new to creating custom modules, but I'm working on it (only way to learn...right?)

How would I go about doing this as I'm currently getting an error when trying. I have a role: 'venue admin' that will be responsible for adding other users with the role of 'customer'. I already am using the module: Role Delegation to handle the permissions side of things. But on the User Registration screen, I would like the customer role to be pre-selected and hidden from display.

This is what I have so far:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 */

function mandatory_role_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state,   &$form_id) { 
global $user;

if(in_array('venue admin', $user->roles)) {   
// by default notify user of new account is checked  
    $form['account']['notify']['#default_value'] = TRUE;
// the only role the venue admin role can create is a customer so this is checked and hidden.
    $form['account']['roles']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

obviously, this is not complete and missing the ability to set the role. Any suggestions?

Comment: If user is not logged in, how can you check in_array(). If user is not logged he will always be an anonymous user. So, it will never come inside of if condition

Comment: The venue admin is logged in and has access to create other users. I substantiated the global user object and can print inside the condition

Comment: I Think you have to remove #access line and use hide() function to hide option elements

Comment: What does the error you are getting look like?

Comment: I'm less concerned about hiding the roles as I can do that with css at the very least, but I would like to set the role by default on the user register screen when the admin is logged in.

Comment: Be with you in a second, looking at this right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well..after staring at this question and trying a bunch of things on my own I think I stumbled upon the answer. Using HOOK_user_presave did the trick! This helped immensely: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/79065/28353

```
function mandatory_role_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
global $user;
if(in_array('venue admin', $user->roles)) {
  if($account ->is_new) {
    $roles = user_roles(TRUE);
    $rid = array_search('customer', $roles);
    if($rid != FALSE) {
      $edit['roles'][$rid] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```